# Boost listings with photos using Sunspot Solr

Tags: solr, sunspot

I need to boost Foobars with photos. I have tried the following:

```
class Foobar < ActiveRecord::Base  
  searchable do
    text :full_name, :as => :full_name_textp
    boolean :photo do
      self.user.try(:avatar_file_name) != nil ? true : false
    end
    latlon(:location) { Sunspot::Util::Coordinates.new(latitude, longitude) }
    boost { :photo ? 1000 : 1 }
  end
end
```

When I reindex the foobars I get no errors, however, when I search for a local foobar the foobars with photos are not being pushed to the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't figure out how to accomplish this by boosting (not sure if it's possible), but I was able to declare [multiple sorters](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Ordering-and-pagination) simultaneously to achieve the result I was looking for.

```
@dispensers = Dispenser.search do
  fulltext params[:search] 
  with(:location).in_radius(x, y, 15, :bbox => true)
  order_by(:photo, :desc)
end
```

Comment: You can also do boosts during search inside the fulltext block:  

fulltext params[:search] do 
  boost(2.0) {
    with(:photo, true)
  }
end